How can I return an AuthResponse after Google OAuth2 login in a Spring Boot application?
I'm using Google OAuth2 authentication in my Spring Boot application. I want to return an AuthResponse object to the user upon successful login. Currently, I redirect the user to a specific URL after a successful login, but I want to pass the user's information (e.g., user ID, username, profile image URL, and JWT) without using a redirect.
Here is my current code:
@Component
public class CustomOAuth2SuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    private final UserService userService;
    private final JwtService jwtService;
    private final RefreshTokenService refreshTokenService;

    public CustomOAuth2SuccessHandler(UserService userService, JwtService jwtService, RefreshTokenService refreshTokenService) {
        this.userService = userService;
        this.jwtService = jwtService;
        this.refreshTokenService = refreshTokenService;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException {
        OAuth2User oAuth2User = (OAuth2User) authentication.getPrincipal();
        String email = oAuth2User.getAttribute("email");
        String fullName = oAuth2User.getAttribute("name");
        
        if (!userService.existsMail(email) && !userService.checkUser(email)) {
            response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:3000/register?email=" + email + "&fullName=" + fullName);
        } else {
            response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:3000/home");
        }
    }
}

// Security configuration
http
    .oauth2Login(oauth2 -> oauth2
        .successHandler(customOAuth2SuccessHandler)
        .failureUrl("http://localhost:3000/login")
    );

@PostMapping("/login")
public ResponseEntity<RestResponse<AuthResponse>> login(@RequestBody AuthRequest authRequest) {
    AuthResponse response = authService.login(authRequest);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(RestResponse.of(response), HttpStatus.OK);
}

public record AuthResponse(
    Long userId,
    String username,
    String profileImageUrl,
    String accessToken,
    String refreshToken,
    String message
) {}

My Expectation:
When a user successfully logs in with Google, I want to obtain the AuthResponse object. How can I achieve this without redirecting the user to a specific URL? Instead of returning the AuthResponse in JSON format, how can I use it during the redirect?
Thank you for your help!
